# bin range and form a data frame using the boundary.

Tags: r

Suppose I want to generate bins for range 1 to 10

```
round(seq(1,20,length.out=5))
```

the output is

> 1  6 10 15 20

I want to form a data.frame as

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    7   10
[3,]   11   15
[4,]   16   20
```

so the start will be 1,7, 11, 16, and ends are 6, 10, 15, 20, respectively.

Any solution for this?

Comment: how do you choose start? What do you mean by range (is it max-min?)?

Comment: How did you come up with 1, 7, 11, and 16. Was it just 0+1, 6+1, 10+1, 15+1 ?

Comment: Why do you want such a data.frame? You might be able to achieve your final goal easier. Tell us, what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I want to bin a region to equal size small regions. It sounds very like "cut". But I want the non-onverlap boundary of each small bin for further manipulation. More specifically, I am trying to bin a genome region, extract reads mapped on that region. To do so, I need a rangedData, and the data.frame is generated for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = round(seq(1,20,length.out=5))

df = data.frame(a = c(x[1], head(x[-1],-1) + 1), b = x[-1])

df
#   a  b
#1  1  6
#2  7 10
#3 11 15
#4 16 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for the following solution. If you are, you can use `cut` and `sub` function as in my [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108980/r-aggregate-data-in-one-column-based-on-2-other-columns) post:

```
mydata<-round(seq(1,20,length.out=5))
mydata<-as.data.frame(mydata)
names(mydata)<-"V" #name the column as V
mydata$V1<-cut(mydata$V,5) #break the data into five intervals and name that as col V1
mydata$lower<-with(mydata,as.numeric( sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", V1))) #extract lower value
mydata$upper<-with(mydata,as.numeric( sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1",V1))) # extract upper value
myfinaldata<-mydata[,c("lower","upper")] #create data frame of lower and upper values


  > myfinaldata
   lower upper
1  0.981  4.79
2  4.790  8.60
3  8.600 12.40
4 12.400 16.20
5 16.200 20.00
```

**Note**: Although these look like ovelapping intervals, they are not. For example for the first row this means all data>=0.981 but <4.79 where as for the second row, this is >=4.79 and <8.60.