# Using a loop/anything else to write a string of intervals (vector)

Tags: r, loops, character, performance

I did this the hard way and would like to know how you would do it with a loop/faster method. I'm creating labels for levels to use in a cut statement, working with age groups.

```
levels(age_group) <- ("<10","10-19","20-29","30-39","40-49","50-59","60-69","70-79","80-89","90-99","100-109",
             "110-119","120-129","130+")
```

Does anyone have any good ideas about how to do this? The less "<10" and "130+" can be added manually but I'm sure there is a faster way to do the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be best to use the levels generated by `cut`, because your current intervals don't define which end is included.

```
s <- c(-Inf,seq(10,130,10),Inf)
levels(cut(s,s))
#  [1] "(-Inf,10]"  "(10,20]"    "(20,30]"    "(30,40]"    "(40,50]"   
#  [6] "(50,60]"    "(60,70]"    "(70,80]"    "(80,90]"    "(90,100]"  
# [11] "(100,110]"  "(110,120]"  "(120,130]"  "(130, Inf]"
```

If you must use your current intervals, you can use this simple function:

```
strInterval <- function(start, end, by) {
  s <- seq(start, end, by)
  i <- paste(head(s,-1), s[-1]-1, sep="-")
  c(paste0("<",start), i, paste0(end,"+"))
}
strInterval(10,130,10)
#  [1] "<10"     "10-19"   "20-29"   "30-39"   "40-49"   "50-59"   "60-69"  
#  [8] "70-79"   "80-89"   "90-99"   "100-109" "110-119" "120-129" "130+"
```

Comment: Yeah, the labels would go into a publication type thing. (I didn't state that in beginning) so I was looking for something close to finished. This is great though, can there be a tie?

Answer (score 3):

```
cts <- seq(10,130, by=10)
paste(c("<=", cts), c(cts-1, "+") , sep="-")
# [1] "<=-9"    "10-19"   "20-29"   "30-39"   "40-49"   "50-59"   "60-69"  
# [8] "70-79"   "80-89"   "90-99"   "100-109" "110-119" "120-129" "130-+"
```

You said you can adjust the ends as needed, right?

Comment: I'm going to use this too. This is by far the most efficient and concise answer given.

Answer (score 2):

Just plug in the max/min and run the rest of the code.

```
min <- 10
max <- 130

seq1 <- seq(min, max, by = 10)
seq2 <- seq(min-1, max-1, by = 10)

age_group <- c(paste("<", min, sep = ""), rep("foo", length(seq1)-1))

  for (i in 1:(length(seq1)-1)) {

    grp1 <- seq1[i]
    grp2 <- seq2[i+1]

    group <- paste(grp1, "-", grp2, sep = "")

    age_group[i+1] <- group

  }

age_group <- c(age_group, paste(max, "+", sep = ""))

age_group
```

Comment: Man this is a really elegant way of doing it, and needs the least manual editing. I like the fact I only have to change the min and max to run a different string.

Comment: I also really wanted to see a loop because I'll be using it with character vectors too.

Answer (score 1):

My solution posted [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147462/bin-range-and-form-a-data-frame-using-the-boundary/18147941#18147941) but with some changes here (this is applicable only if you are using the `cut` function and using that interval):

```
mydata<-round(seq(1,20,length.out=5))
mydata<-as.data.frame(mydata)
names(mydata)<-"V" #name the column as V
mydata$V1<-cut(mydata$V,5) #break the data into five intervals and name that as col V1
mydata$lower<-with(mydata,round(as.numeric( sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", V1)))) #extract lower value
mydata$upper<-with(mydata,round(as.numeric( sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1",V1)))) # extract upper value
myfinaldata<-mydata[,c("lower","upper")] #create data frame of lower and upper values
myfinaldata$interval<-with(myfinaldata,paste(lower,upper,sep="-"))

 myfinaldata
  lower upper interval
1     1     5      1-5
2     5     9      5-9
3     9    12     9-12
4    12    16    12-16
5    16    20    16-20
```